# What is causing this level shift in my wave?

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge, ringing

Excuse the quality, sorry;

[image]

RED is GATE of Q2.
YELLOW is GATE of Q4.

5V INPUT AT ALL STAGES

What are possible reasons that my H-bridge has a little 'bump' at the turn-off of the high-side?

It's reflected on the Vin(bridge) too;

[image]

Circuit:
[image]
(also [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVrmU.jpg) )

I've added a new shiny ceramic capacitor to the Vbridge and GND connection, but no dice. Could it be that having a ground common to my H-bridge ground is bad? 
Or perhaps the capacitor is refusing to discharge beneath 6V~ for a more obscure reason?

EDIT: It's driving a 15-20mH load, but the bump is present with no-load and resistive loads on the order of 1000R, 100R, 10R.

EDIT2: Also, I've noticed that if I put in above 17V to the bridge, the power supply I'm using just shuts itself down and I have to restart the circuit.

EDIT3: Here's a bunch of images of measurements I made.

---

Q2 DRAIN to GND

[image]

---

Q2 SOURCE to GND

[image]

---

Q1 SOURCE to GND

[image]

---

Q1 and Q2 GATE to GND (10V)

[image]

---

### NEW WAVES

5V H-BRIDGE OUTPUT

[image]

---

10V OUTPUT

[image]

---

Q2 Gate/12V

[image]

---

Comment: What load is the bridge driving? What is the white waveform in the first image?

Comment: 15-20mH, High-side/Low-side. Red and Yellow respectively.

Comment: The voltage at the gate would be intresting too

Comment: @PlasmaHH Well according to my first image that looks to be around 15V high-side, 10V low-side. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @ARMATAV: ah, ok, I wasnt aware that you are referring to the gates with it, I was thinking you meant the drain/source

Comment: @PlasmaHH Oh, I assumed the picture was way too 'white' for people so see, so I wanted to make sure. But yeah, that's the gate voltage, and for some reason the High-side won't turn off until the low side turns on. It sit at 6V~.

Comment: On the upper scope view, exactly what point on the schematic is the orange trace, and exactly what point on the schematic is the white trace?

Comment: @ARMATAV: It would be useful if you edited the information in relation to the schematics into the question, like "red trace is gate of Q2" so that people unfamiliar with your specific circuit, same for the second one. Btw. what exactly is the intended purpose of D5 ?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Those diodes stop gate spikes from destroying the MOSFETs by running it to the source instead, also, I edited in that stuff to the question

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Q2 gate for the 'red/orange' and Q4 gate for the 'yellow/white' trace.

Comment: I suggest you get rid of those 15V Zener diodes.. they are interfering with the gate voltage drive of your boostrapped drivers, not helping.

Comment: @ARMATAV: what is the voltage at the source during the "bump" phase?

Comment: @PlasmaHH It looks like a spike to 6V~, to me. Here, I'll edit it in, too; http://i.imgur.com/NIzKYm8.jpg The 'input' to the bridge was 5V in all these instances.

Comment: @KyranF What about going to higher voltages? My MOSFETs will just instantly suicide themselves to the gate-drain/gate-source capacitance, right?

Comment: I've seen high voltage MOSFET gate drive circuits up to 80V , which are certainly still subject to capacitive effects as you mention, and the FETs Gate voltages definitely cannot handle 80V, yet none of those have anything like the 15V Zeners you have connecting the Source to the Gate

Comment: @KyranF I've made one with a 170VDC rectified mains + 10V gate bias to power a Tesla coil, the gate spikes destroyed it within 5 minutes of operation. http://www.semtech.com/images/datasheet/transient_voltage_protection_of_mosfets.pdf

Comment: It may have been something else, can't say without having the full picture (including test set-up, etc). But I think if you try a quick 1 minute operation without the zeners, you may be able to scope better behaviour. Also that schematic shows a diode clamp to ground, for a floating high side H bridge driver I highly doubt that is intended to work the same.

Comment: @KyranF Okay, I'll give it a shot, thanks. Which diode are you referring to? The IR driver only has floating high-side, the low side is on a separate island as far as I know, so the diode clamp to ground is only going to affect the low side.

Comment: on the schematic, D5 and D6

Comment: @KyranF Your suggestion actually helped a lot, I can drive the coil to higher than 20V now. However, after 28V it shuts itself down. I'm pretty sure it's negative voltage spikes on the gate. Any solution for getting it to not spike down into -10V (which is the threshold for my drivers/FETs to shut everything down)?

Comment: clamp diodes to GND should be fixing that, as you should have for all inductive load circuits. whichever gate/node is getting -10V on it put a high power diode (as in, not a small-signal diode with <1 Watt rating, go for like a 3-5Watt rated one) and place that with the diode cathode to the signal you want to protect, and the anode to GND. During the negative voltage spike, the diode will conduct "forward" from negative V_forward of the diode towards GND. So a schottky will give a max clamped voltage of -0.5V-0.7V depending on the diode, and a standard diode will clamp to -1.1V at worst case

Comment: @KyranF But didn't you tell me, "Also that schematic shows a diode clamp to ground, for a floating high side H bridge driver I highly doubt that is intended to work the same."? The high side is the problem, and I'd just be adding another diode, but with a reverse V max that is greater than the 15V zeners.

Comment: And also, do I go from gate to the source of the high side (since that will connect to ground when the bridge switches), or do I do it straight to ground with a reverse voltage > than the voltage my bootstrap circuit will get?

Comment: @KyranF I have some 600V TVS diodes handy, will they do just fine? Forward drop is some odd 1V~ or something similar.

Comment: you only want to protect the gate, with reference to ground - one issue is that the gate has a floating voltage supply provided by the bootstrap driver. Whatever the "ground" is for the bootstrap circuit, is what you clamp with the diode to the gate to avoid going "negative". Also, -20 may not actually be outside of your MOSFET's gate specs - most have ratings like +-20V or +-25V etc. Check yours. For the low side FET you would clamp diode to ground as I mentioned. With the high side voltage it will be more difficult to work out, but as I said, the high side circuit has it's own "ground".

Comment: 600V rated TVS diode would probably work well enough, but maybe it's overkill.. up to you. I would get ultra-fast response schottky diodes but that is only because I like those in my lower voltage applications hehe.

Comment: Cool beans. Grabbed some fast recovery 300V schottkys, by the way, those spikes are only for gate to actual ground. It's like it is leaking a bit from the floating supply into the normal supply. So I clamped the high side gate to actual ground instead, and then it totally fixed the problem. It keeps the 10V spike at 25VDC to 5V even at 30VDC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward. When Q2 is turned off, Q4 is already off. As a result, the output, LVCoilA, is left at an intermediate voltage. This is probably determined by a combination of the two MOSFETs' off current, combined with the capacitances of each MOSFET, producing a sort of voltage divider. If you look simultaneously at Q2 gate and LVCoilA, you'll see that the gate is set to the bootstrap driver's reference, which is LVCoilA, about 6 volts in this case. Since LVColA is also Q2's source, Q2 is turned off.

When Q4 is turned on, you'll see LVCoilA, as well as Q2's gate, get pulled down to ground.

As for the noise on the voltage bus, in order to make much sense of it, you must simultaneously display (for instance) Q2's gate and +12. As it stands, the two traces differ by x5 on the timebase, and there is no obvious way to be sure which +12 transients occur with which gate events.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. So if I'm getting you properly, you're saying that my measurement of Q2 gate to GND is an incorrect representation of what is actually happening, and that Q2 gate to LVCoilA is turning off correctly? If so, take a look at this (ignore the level shifting); http://i.imgur.com/mhD8E05.jpg that is Q2 gate to LVCoilA, coupled with Q4 gate to GND. Am I good then? Also, on your note about the noise, I will definitely get you guys a proper reading when I'm home in an hour. The thing is that my power supply will shut itself off at 17V, and I think it's the noise doing it.

Comment: I believe you are doing it right. The MOSFET only cares about its gate-source voltage, so that's what you need to measure. And for the love of God, will you please turn off the overhead lights when you take pictures of your scope?

Comment: Hahahahaha, it's so eye-gougingly bright though, I love it. Going to get those readings of the Q2/12V to you.

Comment: Hey mate, here's the gate-Q2/12V reading; http://i.imgur.com/xKZdCh4.jpg Here's two readings, 5V and 10V, of the actual H-bridge output; http://i.imgur.com/Hhftwyh.jpg and http://i.imgur.com/LuXrsOs.jpg

Comment: I suspect that what you're seeing on the 12v line is capacitive coupling of the gate drive through the drain of the MOSFET. Try adding more capacitance to your 12v line: a 10 uF, and a 1000 uF, each to ground, connected as close as you can to the MOSFETs. For the 10 uF and existing 100 uF, tantalums will be better than aluminums. Also, make sure that your grounds and 12v are close to the MOSFETs with thick traces or wires (I don't know your construction technique). Make sure your scope ground is as short as possible, and as close the MOSFET sources as possible.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will wire those caps to my PCB and fix this mess. My drivers/FETs are super close together to kill anything of that sort, so it must be the 12V line itself. In fact, I had to remake this PCB design in order to try and fix this very problem, it just didn't work, no matter how close I put the FETs. So it must just be a lack of 12V line smoothing. Thanks again, I'll let you know when I succeed.

Comment: That helped the spikes a lot, and I think we're sorted in that regard. However, they are still present, and when I drive my coil to around 25V through VBridge, my circuit shuts down. From gate to GND on Q2 (high-side), I get a reverse spike that grows in magnitude as VBridge increases. If it hits -10V on my scope, the circuit shuts down.